# Opening excel docs from the internet clunky

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am writing an excel vba script for my company, and I am having some trouble getting it to work smoothly. In order for my script to do its thing, I need to have two excel documents open which are available on my company's intranet. The below is the code I am currently using:

```
Sub checkForGrids()


Dim IE As Object
Dim link As String

On Error Resume Next




                Set groupGrid = Workbooks(Sheet2.Cells(3, 2).value)


                If groupGrid Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox ("The Service Area Grid is required for this tool to run. Attempting to open now.")
                    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                    link = Sheet2.Cells(3, 3)
                    With IE
                        .Visible = True
                        .Navigate link
                    End With
                End If

                Set groupGrid = Workbooks(Sheet2.Cells(4, 2).value)

                If groupGrid Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox ("The Service Area Grid is required for this tool to run. Attempting to open now.")
                    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
                    link = Sheet2.Cells(4, 3)
                    With IE
                        .Visible = True
                        .Navigate link
                    End With
                End If





End Sub
```

This works just fine, except that you have to click ok on the msgbox, click open and wait before you click ok and open for the second document. My coworkers are clicking the second ok button as soon as it pops up, causing an error.

Is there any smoother way to accomplish this? I would prefer for them not to have to click 'open' at all, but I have been unable to find such a method. Thanks

Comment: `Workbooks.Open Sheet2.Cells(3, 3).Value` Assuming that the cell has an HTTP link to a workbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run IE silently by not making it visible, stop screen updating and use the `Application.StatusBar` method to inform the user as to what is happening.

Alternatively, you could create a small userform that pops up in a non-modal state and then hides when the required code has been run.